# How to inject or autowire a Class type with spring?

Tags: java, spring

How Do I wire this class in Spring.

1) Annotation
2) Xml

note: I can already wire other classes just not sure how to wire a class in this scenario

```
Class<? super Client >

enter code here


public class ClientData2 extends ContainerClass<Client>
{
  public ClientData2(Class<? super Client> type)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
    super(type);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bean of type `Class`, it's the same as everything else - with `@Autowired` / `@Inject` (and optionally `@Qualifier`)

How to create such a bean? Multiple ways:

- xml - using `factory-method="forName"` and `constructor-arg` passing `java.lang.Class`
- using a `FactoryBean` that produces `Class` objects
- java config

However, it is is a bit strange that you need a `Class` object as bean - you can't inject any dependencies in it. Perhaps you can simply inject the class name (with `@Value("${class.name}")`) and then use `Class.forName(..)` in a `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: I prefer the `<value type="java.lang.Class">java.lang.String</value>` approach (where java.lang.String.class is the needed class object).